# php delete content-type frm text

Tags: php, regex

I have some text like `$text="--e89a8f234aade3345704b8477b83 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 this is a text. this is a text. --e89a8f234aade3345704b8477b83 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable this is a text.";`

I want the output as `$output="this is a text. this is a text.";`

One more eg:- `$text="--14dae9340ba954ae0704b84acde9 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 First Name: aaa Last Name: aaa --14dae9340ba954ae0704b84acde9 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 First Name: James Last Name: Cummings --14dae9340b";`

Output should be `$output="First Name: aaa Last Name: aaa";`

I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: This is part of a multipart message body, right?

Comment: In that case you should properly parse it that the given answers don’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are sure that charset is ISO-8859-1 and string does not contain -- :

```
$a=explode("charset=ISO-8859-1",$text);
$b=explode("--",$a[1]);
$output=$b[0];
```

If you're still sure about the charset, but not the --:

```
$aa=substr($text,0,30);
$a=explode("charset=ISO-8859-1",$text);
$b=explode($aa,$a[1]);
$output=$b[0];
```

And if you're not even sure about the charset:

```
$aa=substr($text,0,30);
$a=explode("charset=",$text);
$a2=explode(" ",$a[1]);
$b=explode($aa,$a2[1]);
$output=$b[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match over the string, something like

```
<?php
$text="--14dae9340ba954ae0704b84acde9 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 First     Name: aaa Last\
 Name: aaa --14dae9340ba954ae0704b84acde9 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 First Name: James\
 Last Name: Cummings --14dae9340b";

$cnt = preg_match_all('/ISO-8859-1 (.+?) --/',$text,$array);
$array[1][0], "<br />",$array[1][1];
```

?>

The second element is $array (position 1) contains all the substrings of $text that match the group in the pattern.